# Trying a formula for a new stock trading tracking spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, stock

I am currently trying to create a simple but effective spreadsheet to track stock trading, but I am coming across some barriers. I created a sheet called 'movimentacoes' to basically input in and out (compra e venda), in Portuguese. With that, I want to track every transaction I made, how much I paid, date, ticker, etc etc. That is the easy part.

The hard part now is to collect this information from this sheet into another to create some sort of portfolio, combining multiple buys and sells from the same ticker, also populating some other information such as which broker I used, which field of work is the stock from, etc. And the most important, how many shares I have and how much it is worth. Anyway, I am trying to use a combination of UNIQUE, FILTER and SUMIFS but for some reason I get a parse error.

Could someone assist on where the error is? Or better, am I using the right formula and thinking? Maybe this is not the way?

Please see the screenshot.
[image]

Thanks!

I tried this formula:

```
=UNIQUE(filter('Movimentações'!F2:F5),sumifs('Movimentações'!H2:H5,['Movimentações'!F2:F5],['Movimentações'!F2:F5]>0))
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this formula in any cell of a different sheet will get you the data filtered the way you need:

```java
=UNIQUE(QUERY('Movimentações'!A:L; "Select C,E,F,SUM(H),AVG(I),(SUM(H)*AVG(I)) group by C,E,F OFFSET 1 LABEL SUM(H)'Quantidade',AVG(I)'Preco Medio Pago',(SUM(H)*AVG(I))'Investimento Total'"))
```

Like this based on the sample data:

[image: Example]

This is assuming that:

- **Quantidade**: is the sum of all the values corresponding to the specific group in column H.
- **Preco Medio Pago**: is the average of all the `Preco` values for that group in column I.
- **Investimento Total**: is the product of `Quantidade` and `Preco Medio Pago`.

Feel free to provide more clarity if my assumption is incorrect, a sample of the desired output (even if manually entered) would be helpful to better understand the end goal, I'll gladly update my answer if needed.

---

#### Update:

I created new formulas to match your format and desired output. These have been added to the file but I created a second solution where you can save one Query by changing the format:

```java
=QUERY(QUERY({QUERY('Movimentações'!A2:J;"Select C,D,E,F,(I*-1),(I*-1*J) where A matches 'Venda'");QUERY('Movimentações'!A2:J;"Select C,D,E,F,I,(I*J) where A matches 'Compra'")};"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,sum(Col5),sum(Col6)/sum(Col5) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 label sum(Col5) '',sum(Col6)/sum(Col5) ''";0);"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col5*Col6 where Col5 >0 and Col2 != 'Renda Fixa' label Col1'Corretora', Col2 'Tipo', Col3'Setor',Col4'Ticker', Col5'Quantidade', Col6 'Preço Médio Pago', Col5*Col6 'Investimento Total'")
```

[image: new solution]

```java
=QUERY(FILTER('Movimentações'!A:K;'Movimentações'!G:G);"Select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,datediff(Col7,Col2)/365,Col8,Col9*Col10,datediff(now(),Col2) where Col4 matches 'Renda Fixa' label Col3 'Corretora', Col4 'Tipo', Col5 'Setor', Col2 'Validade', datediff(Col7,Col2)/365 'Anos', Col8 'Taxa a.a', Col9*Col10 'Investimento Total', datediff(now(),Col2) 'Dias em Carteira' format datediff(Col7,Col2)/365 '0'")
```

[image: Solution]

#### Note that:

The Spreadsheet's locale is set to "Brazil" which is requiring the formulas to use `;` instead of `,` as parameter separators in the formulas.

For example:

```java
=IF(Condition;TRUE;FALSE)
```

Instead of:

```java
=IF(Condition,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work... error message. I tried doing some editing, no success. 
Btw, will this query consider the sells? Say, I bought 4 times a stock from coca cola, for example, then I sold them all. This shouldn't be considered in the query.

Comment: @Xamineh That's odd, what error message are you getting? It seems that my assumptions were wrong, could you share a screenshot showing the expected output (you might need to calculate it manually just for the example) so that I could update the Query?

Comment: Error is 'Formula parse error'. I can even share the spreadsheet with you if you don't mind. It might be easier this way I guess.

Comment: The spreadsheet with the sample output would work great! You could use [this process](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?#share_publicly&zippy=%2Cshare-a-file-publicly) making sure that no sensitive data is in the file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update my answer once I find a proper solution.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should be corrected now.

Comment: Thank you very much once again. You're the best! I will try to make a query on my own to calculate profit/loss when I sell a stock. If I get stuck may I bother you some more?

Comment: I have tried for the past week to come with a query for the sold items, but I only was able to figure it out partially. Would you be able to help me out with 1 column of my query, please? Its basically this: I need to get an average of all 'buy' instances of a ticker (quantity X price paid) that matches this list of 'sold' ones in tab Vendas: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qGSWwN5DmKCh8E5hwNFT6xKqpHmQEHTVkpaFvXD_J0/edit?usp=sharing